# How should I initialize Koin DI and using Shared Preferences with it

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I am working on this [pull request](https://github.com/oscarine/oscarine-android/pull/3) on my project where I want to store the token received from the server after login. My project's style is one activity and multiple fragments type and I am having one fragment and a view model associated with it for each of the functionality like login and signup etc.

Now my question is how can I use Koin dependency injection so that I can put all the Shared Preferences code in a view model?

Answer (score 4):

in your app Module define SP

```
single { provideSharedPref(androidApplication()) }

fun provideSharedPref(app: Application): SharedPreferences {
return app.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
    SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE
)
```

}

then inject instance from SP in your viewmodel constructor

Answer (score 3):

may be old question but i will help someone who struggles.

in you module.kt.

```
single { PreferenceHelper.customPrefs(androidContext(),"$any_string") }
```

and in the activity or fragment you can inject like.

```
    private val prefs: SharedPreferences by inject()
```

if anyone need SharedPreferencesHelperClass.

[To Github Library](https://github.com/vicky-droid/UtilsLibrary/blob/master/Utils/src/main/java/com/vigneshtheagarajan/utils/one/PreferenceHelper.kt)

I'm not sure this needs to be mentioned it's my library.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Provides
fun providePreferences(@ApplicationContext context: Context): SharedPreferences {
    return context.getSharedPreferences("sp.key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).